# ConnectionAbortedError in Django

Tags: python, django

Whenever this view is executed my server showed up with some error which I don't know why! the view which I was executing is

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def Signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        passw = request.POST.get('password')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname')
        college = request.POST.get('college_name')
        city = request.POST.get('city')
        country = request.POST.get('country')
        User.objects.create_user(
            username=username, password=passw, email=email)
        Userinfo.objects.create(
            user_name=username, full_name=fullname, user_email=email, college_name=college, city=city, country=country , varified_user=False)
        return Response({'status': 'created'})
```

And what i know after checking my database is my code is executing till   `user_name=username, full_name=fullname, user_email=email, college_name=college, city=city, country=country , varified_user=False)` because I can see the data which I was inserting, now i don't know what error can cause by `return Response({'status': 'created'})`. The message in my terminal is

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
September 29, 2020 - 21:19:18
Django version 3.1, using settings 'backend.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[29/Sep/2020 21:19:31] "POST /api/usercheck/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18
[29/Sep/2020 21:19:34] "POST /api/usercheck/ HTTP/1.1" 200 18
[29/Sep/2020 21:19:35] "POST /api/usercheck/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21
[29/Sep/2020 21:19:58] "POST /signin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3318
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 65332)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "E:\Project_Bookbhandar\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 174, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "E:\Project_Bookbhandar\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 182, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
----------------------------------------
```

Can anyone help with this??

Answer (score 0):

You will want to be using HttpResponse or JsonResponse.

Comment: You are not saving the objects but just creating them. Try saving the data and see if it throws any error?